# Deriving the Ricci tensor on the flat FLRW metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, curvature

I am currently with a difficulty in deriving the space-space components of the Ricci tensor in the flat FLRW metric
$$ds^2 = -c^2dt^2 + a^2(t)[dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2],$$ to find:
$$R_{ij} = \delta_{ij}[2\dot{a}^2 + \ddot{a}a].$$

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you understand the formulas for the Ricci tensor, the Riemann tensor, and the Christoffel symbols? If so, what difficulty are you having applying them in the case of the flat FLRW metric?

Comment: *Please, show step-by-step.* This kind of request will probably ensure that your question gets closed as “homework-like”.

Comment: I do understand the formulas for the Ricci tensor and the Christoffel symbol, but i think i am struggling with the algebra in the final steps because i am finding a very similar result (in despite of the factor 2 in front of the a dot)

Comment: If you have checked your algebra over and over, then maybe there is something about the formulas that you don’t understand. Can you get $R_{tt}=-3\ddot a/a$?

Comment: Although this calculation doesn’t need a computer algebra system, a CAS would help you find your error.

Comment: I did get the time-time component of the Ricci tensor. 
What is this CAS, though? (I am new in the research area)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system

Comment: I’ll take a look. Thank you @Ghoster.

Comment: I usually use the "ccgrg" package for mathematica, although you have to force  older versions of mathematica as  recent version have broken things. (See https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2482121 ) it gets Ricci in a few seconds,

Comment: See [here](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/25.html#5) at Input 5, that also works with modern versions.

Comment: @gabriel wrote: *"in despite of the factor 2 in front of the a dot"* - I don't know what you did, but if you sum the components you have to sum the crossterms twice since Rabcd=Rcdab etc.